# Algorithm for deciding feasibility of linear programs

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming

Suppose I have the simple linear program

$$Ax \geq 0, \quad x \geq 0$$

We know that this system has a solution (for example, $x=0$). But, what if we made this rule for this system?

$$Ax \geq 0, \quad e^T x > 0$$

where $e = (1, 0, \dots, 0)$. Rewriting,

$$Ax \geq 0, \quad x_1 > 0$$

Is there a way to decide whether this system has solutions or not before using some algorithms to solve it?

Comment: You may want to take a look at Kroening & Strichman's [Decision Procedures — An Algorithmic Point of View](https://www.decision-procedures.org)

Comment: Thank you for editing and book!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, sorry, I had trouble with my net. A is fat and I already used Farkas' lemma to get this system (I thought that this system will be easier to analyze for a solution). I can write you whole what I got.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, the main task was to understand if $$Ax \geq b$$ have a solution for polynomical time? From this task I've made a same task with other system (by Alexandrov' and Fan Ky alternative) $$-e=Bx, x \geq 0$$  where e = (1,0,...0) and B = [b, A] (matrix where first row is b from first system).
Then by Farkas' lemma I've got this system (in the question).

Comment: If you have an LP solver, you can simply solve the linear program $$$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & 0\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \mathrm x \geq \mathrm b\end{array}$$$$

Comment: Delete and repost at https://‎cstheory.stackexchange.com